# Differential equation: $\frac {dy}{dx}=\frac {1}{x \cos y +\sin 2y}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I tried to solve the following equation: $$\frac {\text{d}y}{\text{d}x}=\frac {1}{x \cos y +\sin 2y}$$

Checked if it were an exact differential equation. Then I tried finding the integrating factor. Got stuck doing so.

Comment: Not sure how to do this off the top of my head, but [wolfram alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=dy%2Fdx+%3D+1%2F%28x+cos%28y%29+%2B+sin%282y%29%29) seems to...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

re write the differential equations as $$(x\cos y + \sin 2y)dy = \cos y(x + 2\sin y )dy = dx$$

make a change change of variable $u = \sin y$ which transforms the $(x + 2\sin y )\cos ydy = dx$ to $$(x + 2u)du = dx,\  \frac{dx}{du} = x + 2u$$ look for a particular solution of the form 
$$ x = Au + B$$ shows that $A  = B =-2$ and the solution to the homogeneous problem is $Ce^u.$ putting the two together, the general solution is $$x = Ce^u-2u-2, \mbox{ where $C$ is any constant.} $$

this is an implicit relation between $x$ and $u = \sin y.$

Answer (score 4):

Hint:First write it as $\frac {\text{d}x}{\text{d}y}={x \cos y +\sin 2y}$. Now this is a linear equation in $x$. Multiply by $e^{-\sin y}$ and make the equation exact.